# Raspberry Pi use Webcam instead of PiCam

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, webcam, opencv3.0, raspberry-pi3

Here is the code to initialize raspberry camera by pyimagesearch blog.I want to add a webcam to capture frame by frame in

```
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = tuple(conf["resolution"])
camera.framerate = conf["fps"]
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=tuple(conf["resolution"]))

for f in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
    # grab the raw NumPy array representing the image and initialize
    # the timestamp and occupied/unoccupied text
    frame = f.array
```

This is the part that continuously captures frames from PiCamera. The problem is that I want to read frame by frame from webcam too. I somehow got it working, But lost the code accidentally. Now I don't remember what did I do. I got it working in just about 2-3 extra lines. Please help me get it if you can. Thank you.